# How can I check if a string is a whole number in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm

I have recently encountered a problem in which I had a string array inputted by the `argv[]` to check if it is a whole number or not.

I tried to use `isdigit()`. However, it returns `"20x"` as a whole number. I searched a lot, but could not find anything helpful for C language.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at `atoi()`?

Comment: Yes I have, atoi when used in "20x" still accept it as an integer value "20"

Comment: Make sure the string is null-terminated and iterate over it using `isdigit` on each character. If you actually need to convert the string to an `int`, then don't do that. Just use `strtol` (or one of its sibling functions) and try to convert, and check for errors. Do not use `atoi` as it can't report errors.

Comment: `isdigit` check if a _character_ is a _digit_. You have to loop over characters, and for each character check if it's a digit.

Comment: This is actually surprisingly difficult. Without sounding facetious it depends on what you mean by a number! A number is a bit more than something than can be represented by an out-of-the box C type. For example, `1.000 + 0i` is a whole number but is a pain to parse. Then you have to get round C's annoying convention of leading zeros denoting octal constants, so techniques that will throw out 08 for example will need to be avoided. So, what do you need exactly?

Comment: @Bathsheba  For this program, I need to make a distinction between numbers such as integers for those who have for example "20x" or "20a3a". Hope you could understand

Comment: @carvalho28: In which case, use isdigit on each character, allowing for a prefix + and -.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Requires `stdbool.h` and `ctype.h`]

```
bool isWholeNumber(char* num)
{
    // Check if the input is empty
    if (*num == '\0') return false;

    // Ignore the '+' sign if it is explicitly present in the beginning of the number
    if (*num == '+') ++num;

    // Check if the input contains anything other than digits
    while (*num)
    {
        if (!isdigit(*num)) return false;
        ++num;
    }

    // You can add other tests like
       // Ignoring the leading and trailing spaces
       // Other formats of whole number (1.0, 1.00, 001, 1+0i, etc.)
       // etc. (depends on your input format)

    // The input is a whole number if it passes these tests
    return true;
}
```

This should work for large whole numbers as well.

I hope you got the logic and the way of approaching this task. Simply iterate through each character in the string and validate them according to your need.

Comment: what about a leading `-`?

Comment: @Ackdari Whole numbers don't have a leading `-`. Maybe you mistook the question for integers.

Comment: Well according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number) the term is ambiguas. But yes seems like it.

Comment: @Ackdari Haha, I see. Even the entire question is ambiguous because the OP hasn't given a clear description of the input string. Well, if someone needs to ignore the trailing minus sign as well then change `if (*num == '+')` to `if (*num == '+' || *num == '-')`

Answer (score 0):

You check per character in your char array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
   ch = charArray[i];
   if('0' <= ch && ch <= '9'){
      // it's a character number (in decimal)
   }
   // you do with other conditions: formated number, .....
}
```